# How can I convert a number in my database to a color when echoing it in a table? (SQL PHP)

Tags: php, html, sql

I made a echo table in PHP and when I test it, it gives me my table with data.

```
id    material    state    date
1     gold        100      2018-16-11
2     iron        75       2018-16-11
3     silver      25       2018-16-11
```

This is my table above. I can display this as a table, but I want it to be colored. When a state is higher than 80, it should be green, between 50 and 80 it should be yellow etc.

How to do it?

Comment: show your code for creating the table currently, please. Basically the solution is just to use an `if` statement to check the state value on the row you're generating, and use that to set the CSS style of the row accordingly. Did you try to research this at all?

Comment: Well, the first step would be writing some code that determines whether the value is within a certain range.  Have you made any attempt to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in alot of ways. This should work

```
<td style="background-color:<?php if($state > 80){ echo 'green';} elseif($state > 50 && $state < 80){ echo 'yellow'} ?>;"> 
    <?php echo $state; ?> 
</td>
```